# "list indices must be integers, not list" while accesing elements of a list of lists

Tags: python, list, syntax-error

This lines of my code

```
    v_recorrido= [[4, 45], [4, 15], [4, 45]]      

    t=0
    for i in v_recorrido:
        seg = 60*v_recorrido[i][0] + v_recorrido[i][1]
```

are throwing me this error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list

Why? I am new to Python (coming mainly from C++) but I have checked the documentation for the syntax and it seems to be right.

Comment: Have you looked up the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) for the `for` statement? Or checked out the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)? This behavior is _extremely thoroughly documented_.

Comment: Putting this question's exact title into a Google search instead of SO's "ask question" box would've been useful, too.

Answer (score 0):

Python for loops are what is described in some other languages as "for-each" loops. That is, `i` in each iteration is not an index, but the actual element in `v_recorrido`. So:

```
seg = 60*i[0] + i[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in v_recorrido:
    seg = 60*v_recorrido[i][0] + v_recorrido[i][1]
```

This is what is in some languages called a for-each loop, meaning the iteration variable takes on the *value* of each of the elements, not the index of the element. The error is because you are trying to subscript `v_recorrido` using its elements.

Change it to:

```
for i in v_recorrido:
    seg = 60*i[0] + i[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, i is actually a list item. In the first iteration it is equal to [4, 45], then [4, 15] and finally [4, 45].

What you might be looking for is to iterate over a range equal to the length of v_recorrido. Like:

```
for i in range(len(v_recorrido)):
  ....
```